# pcre2: include a static library in c++ CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, pcre2

need to include pcre2 static library in my CMake project.

1. I've built last version of pcre2 from official sources and got libpcre2-32.a (I need 32-bit char width libray)
2. Put it in my project folder, with its header pcre2.h
3. Have added this library to CMakeLists.txt:

> ```
> ...
> include_directories(SupportFiles/OSLinux/pcre2)
> ...
> add_library(libpcre2 STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
> find_library(libpcre2_path NAMES libpcre2-32.a HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SupportFiles/OSLinux/pcre2/ REQUIRED NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH)
> message(">>>>>> libpcre2_path = ${libpcre2_path}")
> set_property(TARGET libpcre2 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${libpcre2_path})
> target_link_libraries(appservicehttpmodule PRIVATE libpcre2)
> ...
> ```

Library was found in my project and no CMake errors are.

4. Have added simple pcre2 code in my project

> ```
> #define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 32
> #include "pcre2.h" 
> ... 
> pcre2_code *pcode = pcre2_compile(...)
> ```

get an error :

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/UnitTest.dir/test.cpp.o: in function `moduleTest_pcre2Presence_Test::TestBody()':
> /home/.../GoogleTest/test.cpp:248: undefined reference to `pcre2_compile_32'
> ```

What is wrong?
Why this lib is not linked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did. I use 'target_link_libraries()' in CMakeLists.txt to link with specific library which is in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I don't have enough reputation to leave comments :( )*

The linker error seems to be from a separate executable (a unit test). Does it have `libpcre2` added as a dependency (using `target_link_libraries()`)?

Comment: That is the point! Thank you! Everything is fine now. Google test has a different target, so target_link_libraries() for another target (CMakeLists.txt) resolved the problem. Me had to pay attention :)